# Style broken and pixelated in a bootstrap modal using google chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, modal-dialog, styles

I have an issue with the boostrap modals using the Inspinia theme. When i select a combobox or the tags input, the style of the modal brokes and gets pixelated. We didn't change any style file, somebody knows if it's a chrome issue?

[here's a picture of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOeKb.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an [open issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/24233) on the Bootstrap GitHub. Apparently, it is a bug in Chrome on Windows with GPU acceleration enabled. I guess we'll just have to wait until Chrome or Bootstrap release a fix.